# DotNetNuke Installation Wizard Keeps on Loading

Tags: asp.net, windows-8, installation, sql-server-2012, dotnetnuke

Coming to straight to the point. I am installing DNN and the installation wizard just keeps on loading and loading. Even if I fill the fields but links are not working. Apparently javascript hasn't loaded properly.

And at the bottom of the page I get the error

"No valid default database connection detected. Standard Database setup option is unavailable
Database Connection Error"

The connection string in my web.config is

connectionString="Server=QANITA-NOTEBOOK; Database=DotNetNuke; User ID=qanita; Password=123456;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

I am having no problem when I try to connect from Sql Management Studio using the username and password mentioned in connection string. Can anybody help me here?

Comment: One simple thing you can try installing it with your virus scanner off.  Also make sure you have the latest version(s) of all your prerequsitie programs.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect using SSMS are you using the servername QANITA-NOTEBOOK or are you using LOCAL

You could also try a single period . for the servername.

In the web.config, be sure to look at the comment areas `<!-- -->`, as the default connectionstring in DNN is for SQL Express, and your string might be commented out.

Comment: I have commented out sql express string. i am using qanita-notebook and i have tried two versions of dnn and the same problem persists.

Comment: and i can connect to the database within visual studio as well. i created a table and then dropped it within visual studio via this connection string so i am pretty damn sure there is no issue in sql server connection. any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the fill CONNECTIONSTRING section and the AppSettings portion of the web.config in the original question? Without seeing your config it is hard to guess

Comment: I don't know what exactly the issue is. I tried dnn visual studio starter kit, dnn quick install and zip install. I can't browse the extracted directory or my visual studio project from iis. but I can browse dnn quick installed website using iis. all of the projects work fine if I try to browse them using iis express. its so strange and weird. And complicated.  :-(

Comment: You should follow the steps in the Installation tutorial videos step for step. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training/Tutorials.aspx you are likely missing a key step along the way